# Can I load a big image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, uiimageview

I was wondering what is the biggest image size I can use as background in a UIVIEW.

I have an image of size 320 by 1700 which is scrollable and was wondering if this is going to be an issue loading it to the heap mem.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: Prior to iOS 3.0, UIView
>   instances may have a maximum height
>   and width of 1024 x 1024. In iOS 3.0
>   and later, views are **no longer
>   restricted to this maximum size** but
>   are still limited by the amount of
>   memory they consume. Therefore, it is
>   in your best interests to keep view
>   sizes as small as possible. Regardless
>   of which version of iOS is running,
>   you should consider using a
>   CATiledLayer object if you need to
>   create views larger than 1024 x 1024
>   in size.

Ref: [iPhone Docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1)

Comment: Thanks I will keep that in mind, mine is 320 by 1700 which is about 1/2 the area of a 1024 by 1024 image.